# Drawing an arrow using the LineRenderer in unity

Tags: unity, line-renderer

I'm trying to draw an arrow using a `LineRenderer` in Unity, using the code suggested [here](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1330338/view.html).

Based on the UI it all seems good, yet it draws a pin needle, rather than the arrow I would expect from the UI. If I understand the UI right, it should thicken 60% into the line and then become thinner again towards the end.

Any idea what might be going wrong?
[image: Unity UI]

Comment: How many positions did you define in your line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you can make arrows with **linerenderer** but its not the best approach. line renderer is for effects and drawing. its hard to customize colliders to it. you can just use an **spriteRenderer** for this. but for a good Drawing i show you my inspector to how work with it.

you have to uncheck **"Use World Space"** to be able to update its position by **Transform** and add more **points** to your lineRenderer. and customize Width dependeing on you needs.

[image]